# Apply filter in MongoDB if function argument provided

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using TypeScript, Node.js, Mongoose and MongoDB. If I have a function similar to:

```
async function getAllBooks(title?: string, authorName?: string, sortBy?) {
    const books = await bookModel.find().sort();

    return books;
}
```

How would I go about only applying the title and authorName filter if they are provided? Likewise, how would I only sort the query if the sortBy parameter is provided? Is there a common best practice for this?

For instance if I provide the title and sortBy field I want the query to look like this:

```
async function getAllBooks(title?: string, authorName?: string, sortBy?) {
    const books = await bookModel.find(title: title).sort(sortBy.field: sortBy.sortDirection);

    return books;
}
```

Comment: Basically it is the same as not providing the field if you provide `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, modify the find object according to the arguments:

```
async function getAllBooks(title?: string, authorName?: string, sortBy?) {
  let findThis = {};
  if(title) findThis.title=title;
  if(authorName) findThis.authorName=authorName;
 
  const books = await bookModel.find(findThis).sort(sortBy.field: sortBy.sortDirection).exec();

  return books;
}
```

Add **[exec()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec)** or it will never run.